# Updating profile information

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, ampscript

I currently have a Microsite that when the user who received an email clicks the link, it populates their information in text fields.

For example:

```
First name: %%first_name%%
Last name: %%last_name%%
Etc.
```

**Edit - current code sample**

```
<form action=" http://cl.exct.net/subscribe.aspx" name="subscribeForm" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="thx" value="YOUR THANK YOU PAGE HERE" />
<input type="hidden" name="err" value="YOUR ERROR PAGE HERE" />
<input type="hidden" name="usub" value="YOUR SUCCESS UNSUB PAGE HERE" />
<input type="hidden" name="MID" value="YOUR MEMBER ID HERE" />
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td><font face="Verdana" size="2">Name:</font></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Full Name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><font face="Verdana" size="2">Company Name:</font></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="User Defined" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><font face="Verdana" size="2">Email:</font></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Email Address" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><font face="Verdana" size="2">Subscriber Key</font></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Subscriber Key" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="Email Type" value="HTML" checked="checked" />
            <font face="Verdana" size="2">HTML</font>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="Email Type" value="TEXT" />
            <font face="Verdana" size="2"> Text</font>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="SubAction" value="sub" checked="checked" />
            <font face="Verdana" size="2">Subscribe</font>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="SubAction" value="unsub" />
            <font face="Verdana" size="2">Unsubscribe</font>
        </td>
    </tr
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </td>
        <td align="right">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

My goal is to have the user be able to update this information and save it, does anyone know how I can go about this?

Comment: Is there something you have already tried - this question is very broad and would be difficult to answer.

Comment: Yes sorry, at first I was using this example: http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/web_collect/#Sample_Code_for_Subscribing_to_or_Unsubscribing_from_Multiple_Lists

Comment: This example works great for updating list, but if I were to delete the list part and just use the text fields, an error is returned stating not all required fields are entered.

Comment: I guess I'm looking for a form action that does not require list information, I just need profile info (first name, etc )

Comment: The `web collect` feature allows for complete management - including what lists the subscriber is subscribed to.  You can set those fields to hidden, or create a custom profile page.  However - not allowing subscribers to opt-in/opt-out of messages is not good practice.

Comment: I was actually able to develop an opt in/out out section in the page but I was really hoping for just a section to update info

Comment: That will require custom functionality, and not web collect. Ill dig up updating subscribers. It will require SOAP

Comment: If you could find it, that would be awesome. I appreciate the rewording of the question.... I'm on mobile and it's not so easy

Comment: @KellyJAndrews any updates? thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19586/discussion-between-user3087325-and-kelly-j-andrews).

Answer (score 3):

Web Collect won't help you in this situation.  That's generally for adding subscribers to a list.

If you're wanting to allow the subscribers to update their info,  [here's](https://gist.github.com/wvpv/19777e1167d6ac91e2e8) a skeleton of the code that I normally use when building custom SFMC preference centers using AMPScript and SSJS API functions.

The general process is:

1. The user clicks on a URL in an email
2. The page retrieves the subscriber attributes or URL parameter values and sets default form values
3. The page is set to post to itself and upon form submission an API call is made to update the appropriate object in ET.

Some tips and tricks...

- Understand the SFMC data model and how subscriber statuses are handled for your account type (global, business unit, publication). Things are handled differently in an [**Enterprise 1.0**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/enterprise/enterprise_overview/) account than they are in an [**Enterprise 2.0**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/enterprise/enterprise_20_overview/) account.
- Use [**Server-Side JavaScript**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/server_side_javascript/) to leverage arrays and functions. The coding can be done entirely in AMPScript, but it's easier to create object-oriented code in SSJS.
- Utilize the [**SOAP examples**](http://help.exacttarget.com/Global/Documentation/APIStarterKits/SOAPv3.zip) when structuring your API calls
- Be sure to correctly [**log unsub events**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/unsubscribing_and_logging_an_unsubevent_with_a_logunsubevent_execute_call.htm) when handling unsubscribes

I normally build preference centers in 4 pages.

1. **Subscription Center Page** - subscribers opt-in and out of lists or publications marked as Public.
2. **Profile Center Page** - subscribers update their information (emailaddress, name, zipcode, etc).
3. **One-Click Unsubscribe Page** - subscribers are immediately unsubscribed from the publication used as the send audience in your ET account (or globally if it's not specified)
4. **Results Page** - a thank your or error page depending on the action taken on pages 1-3.

Comment: Do either of you have working sub centers live that I can get some style ideas from